# Is this a valid date format - 2007-12-13+01:00?

Tags: java, date, soap, jaxb, axis

We have a very strange situation. **We expect some data from web service** and then we process it in java code. Suddenly, it started to fail.

We found out, that we receive the date in such format:  **2007-12-13+01:00** and it throws out an exception: *java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time*. We use JAXB to Marshall the response and expect date to be **java.util.Date**. So far I didn't find any line of a code which handles the date, no trimming, converting or anything. Just marshaling.

Now there is a dispute whether this format is correct or incorrect and who caused this problem. Funny thing is, that there were no changes done in java code recently, the only difference is in the computer on which the build was made.

Might this be caused by different java version, ANT configuration? Do you have any suggestions what else can cause such problem? If you have any questions, please ask. I'll try to answer if it's possible.

[LOG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6LvsaTzXwsWNEtEMUNXQXJTTW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `We found out, that we receive the date in such format`. Where does the source of the document come from?

Comment: Where is the date coming from? Surely some code produces it, from file or database or calculation?

Comment: It's a web service of our client. For us it's a black box, I can't really tell, how it is generated.

Comment: But our logs suggest that before we received date in format 2007-12-13 and it went flawlessly.

Comment: @dallows Please accept an answer you determine to be correct. Look for the large empty checkmark icon below the Up triangle and Down triangle, and click it. [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27986774/642706) by Blaise Doughan seems spot-on correct to me.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just couldn't decide, what was the best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Is this a valid date format - 2007-12-13+01:00?

Yes, see the link below for the official description of the format:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date-lexical-representation

---

## Your Error

> We found out, that we receive the date in such format:
>   2007-12-13+01:00 and it throws out an exception:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

This appears to be a bug in Axis and not JAXB.

---

## Handling this format in JAXB

Below is an example of working with this format in JAXB.

### Java Model

In this example we will use `Date`, `Calendar`, and `XMLGregorianCalendar` to handle the dates:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private Date date;
    private Calendar cal;
    private XMLGregorianCalendar xgc;

}
```

### Demo Code

**input.xml**

Below is the XML document we will unmarshal, note how all the date values are the same as in your question.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <date>2007-12-13+01:00</date>
    <cal>2007-12-13+01:00</cal>
    <xgc>2007-12-13+01:00</xgc>
</foo>
```

**Demo**

Below is some demo code where we will unmarshal an XML document to populate each of the date fields and then marshal the object back to XML.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code, we see that all the values got converted properly.  Note that the `Date` and `Calendar` values default to the default dateTime representation.  You can control this using the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <date>2007-12-12T18:00:00-05:00</date>
    <cal>2007-12-13T00:00:00+01:00</cal>
    <xgc>2007-12-13+01:00</xgc>
</foo>
```

Comment: Nice explanation of JAXB-handling of date-offset-combination.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it's a valid ISO-8601 (or [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)) format, which is what's usually used for web services - that only appears to include time zone offsets when a time is specified as well.

However, as noted in comments, it *is* a valid [XML schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date-lexical-representation) representation:

> The lexical space of **date** consists of finite-length sequences of characters of the form: `'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd zzzzzz?` where the date and optional timezone are represented exactly the same way as they are for **dateTime**. The first moment of the interval is that represented by: `'-' yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T00:00:00' zzzzzz?` and the least upper bound of the interval is the timeline point represented (noncanonically) by: `'-' yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T24:00:00' zzzzzz?`.

It sort of makes sense if you want to represent a whole day in a specific time zone - although as it only specifies the offset rather than a zone ID, it fails for 23 or 25 hour days with daylight saving transitions :(

I can't say I've personally ever seen it used in the wild though, nor modeled in date/time APIs.

Comment: An XML Schema date can have a time zone, see:  http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date-lexical-representation

Answer (score 1):

The official [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) paper says (cannot link to it because it requires you to buy it):

> The zone designator is empty if use is made of local time in
>   accordance with 4.2.2.2 through 4.2.2.4, it is the UTC designator [Z]
>   if use is made of UTC of day in accordance with 4.2.4 and it is the
>   difference-component if use is made of local time and the difference
>   from UTC in accordance with 4.2.5.2.

I interpret this statement in a way as if zone designators are only sensible in context of any time component. So the answer is:

➥ **Your input string is not really [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant, but is [XML-schema compliant](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date-lexical-representation)** as you should expect from a web service using [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/). See the citation in the good sibling Answers, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27986774/642706) by Blaise Doughan and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27984687/642706) by Jon Skeet.

So yes, you must take into account the possibility that a XML-compatible web service will provide such data (although very questionable, it is more probable that the web service had simply failed to deliver a complete date-time due to an internal error).

How you interpret the combination of date and offset is another good question. XML-schema speaks about the interpretation as an interval (a full day), but this interval is not mappable 1:1 to a point in time (your [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) result). Probably you should simply assume midnight and use the offset to map the result to `java.util.Date`. Or better: You should ask the responsible persons behind the web service why they offer such data and how to interpret it.

By the way, I remember that [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) (built into [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29)) originally planned to introduce the type `OffsetDate` in analogy to [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) but has finally dropped it.

Comment: I've managed to get the log, that took some time. Now I can see there is also AXIS involved.